# AS does not find symbol, even after importing TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am learning how to do Android development right now and arrived at this tutorial on Google's website:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

However after following the instructions - I'm assuming I missed something - here is what I get in AS:

[image]

And so Gradle will not compile it.

Comment: Those statements need to be moved inside a method body

Comment: clean project and try ..............

Comment: Thanks, the solution seemed to be that I had to move the block of code in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create an xml and declare things in it .in resource->lay out folder   for  using this things in java in

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/t_id"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      />
```

and in java class file

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_id);
```

and you should declare and use the text view inside oncreate function

Comment: Ok it seems putting the block of code inside the onCreate method solved the problem.

Comment: What I am wondering now is why is AS formatting/displaying the same way with a different code color? It compiles perfectly and all that, but for some reason most of the block of code besides the arguments passed in the methods are in grey.

Comment: colors will differ for objects and functions of that objects

Comment: You mean whether they belong to an object or they are their own standalone object?

Answer (score 0):

Set the text for your text view inside the `onCreate()` Method , because you cant access layout elements before calling `setContentView()` .

Different Data Types values have different colours .
for eg :

```
int = blue ,
string = green ,
```

and so on ...